# How to make a text document matrix with huge number of tags

Tags: text-mining

I want to build and processes a term document matrix with huge columns(30000+). So can anybody suggest what should the best practice to build such kind of matrix

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to make a text document matrix..

```
tdm.onlytags <- tdm[rownames(tdm)%in%TagSet$tag,]
```

This code will help you...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But my concern is my csv file is huge in size (8Gb +) and the tags are more than 30000+, so will this approach work for me ?

Comment: It work for me try it and if any issues arise inform in this thread.